# Group Elements in Mathematica v10 using (x,y,z) notation

Tags: group-theory

I have a group generated by this condition `G = {(x,y,z): x^3=y^3=z^3=e}}` and I want to compute all the possible elements i.e `(x,y,z) (x,y^2,z)`.. there are 27 elements of G and then find the generators of the Group G.

Any suggestions of how to solve such problem since GroupElements is not giving the results needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately no, I wish to compute all the elements possible having this condition [x^3 == y^3 == z^3 == e, {x, y, z}], 

For example (x,y,z),      (x^2,y,z),     (x^3,y^2,z)
                     (x,y^2,z), (x^2,y^2,z), (x^3,y^2,z) and so on

Comment: Not sure about your question and your condition, but is this the result you want? `Power[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ Tuples[Range[3], {3}]`

Comment: Quantum_Oli, yes thank you, the remaining tasks are:
 1) finding the generators which generate the whole group
2)  a set containing the least possible generators which construct G.

Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to software Mathematica. This question should belong to https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -1):

Since all elements have order 3 (save (e,e,e)) I think that you cannot have less than three generators - say (x,e,e), (e,y,e), (e,e,z). But I would not like to automate the search for a subset of generators for any group given by relations (there are opensource programs that can do that well).